# Using Jquery, Spring MVC and ajax form with text field and textarea not persisting values to DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring, hibernate

I am using Jquery, Spring MVC ,hibernate and ajax with bootstrap. I have a generate button that opens a modal and the modal form consists text fields, text areas and checkbox. The input with check box is getting persisted to DB and the value i put to the text area is showing as "[object HTMLCollection]" in my DB and the text field input is not getting persisted at all, it shows null values. Below is my code snippet: Could some one help why i dont get all the fields get persisted. Thanks.

My Modal in JSP:

```
<div id="generateCertModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    Generate
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">



                    <table class="form-table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr valign="top">
                                <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                    class="not-required" for="pool-name">FQDN/IP-Adress:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="commonName" 
                                    class="form-control" /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                               <div style="margin-left:18px">
                                 <label class="checkbox">
                                 <input type="checkbox" id="export"  title="Enalbe or Disable Export Control">
                                Export Control Enable?
                                 </label>
                                </div>
                               </td>
                             </tr>


                            <tr valign="top">
                                <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                    class="not-required" for="description">Organization:</label></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="organization" title="Company Name" path="#"
                                    class="form-control" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <div style="margin-left:18px">
                            <label class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="activateGenerateTxt" onclick="activateGenerateTextArea()" title="Please Enter the Certificate Signing Request if Required">
                                Is CSR required?
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                            <tr valign="top">
                                <td style="width: 25% !important;"></td>
                                <td><textarea id="csaGenerate" path="#" 
                                    class="form-control" disabled></textarea></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr valign="top">
                                <td style="width: 25% !important;"><label
                                    class="not-required" for="expire-after">Descritption:</label></td>
                                <td><textarea id="description" path="#" class="form-control" "></textarea></td>
                            </tr>


                        </tbody>
                    </table>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" id="generateCsa" value="Generate"
                            class="btn btn-default" onClick="doGenerateCert()" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My script.JS

```
function doGenerateCert(){
var commonName= $('#commonName').val();
var export= $('#export').val();
var organization= $('#organization').val();
var csa= $('#csaGenerate').val();
var des= $('#description').val();

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
     url : "Generate",
    data : "commonName="+ commonName + "&export=" + export +  "&organization=" + organization +
      "&csa=" + csa + "&description=" + description ,
    success : function(response){
        alert('Generated');
    }
});
```

}

My Model:

```
@Entity
public class Certificate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String commonName;
    private String organization;
    private String description;
    private String csa;
    private String export;

public Certificate() {

    }

public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCsa() {
        return csr;
    }

    public void setCsa(String csa) {
        this.csa = csa;
    }

    public String getCommonName() {
        return commonName;
    }

    public void setCommonName(String commonName) {
        this.commonName = commonName;
    }



    public String getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(String organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }




    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getExport() {
        return export;
    }

    public void setExport(String export) {
        this.export = export;
    }


}
```

My DAO:

```
  @Override
    public void generateCertificate(Certificate cert) {
        sf.getCurrentSession().persist(cert);

    }
```

My Service:

```
 @Override
    public void generateCertificate(Certificate cert) {
        certificateDao.generateCertificate(cert);

    }
```

My Controller;

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Generate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String generateCert(Certificate cert) {

        certificateService.generateCertificate(cert);

        return "GenerateHome";
    }
```

Comment: In fact there's no need to use `input type="submit"`, you don't have a form to use a submit button, use `type="button"` instead, and can you please share your web service implementation?

Comment: I have shared all the implementation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Generate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String generateCert(@ModelAttribute("certificate ") Certificate cert) {

    certificateService.generateCertificate(cert);

    return "GenerateHome";
}
```

Comment: @ModelAttribute is used if you want to bind the object from controller to JSP. Here I am sending the object value from jsp to Controller so i can use the object it self(Certificate certificate), this is working. The issue is with my textarea, it is persisting the checkbox values but not the text field and textarea.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but u r sending the object instead of the value....

change `"&description=" + des` ,

```
var csa= $('#csaGenerate').val();
var des= $('#description').val();

$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
     url : "Generate",
    data : "commonName="+ commonName + "&export=" + export +  "&organization=" + organization +
      "&csa=" + csa + "&description=" + des ,
    success : function(response){
        alert('Generated');
    }
});
```